# Facebook notification as link to website content

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm creating a job listing website. Currently, when member register, he asked to like our app in facebook. I want to create a new job offer on my website and inform my registered user in facebook via notifications. This notification should be a link to job offer in my website.

Is it possible? If so, what resources should I learn?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications):

> Currently, only apps on Facebook.com can use App Notifications.

Meaning, App Notifications are not available (or should not be used) on external websites.

That being said, Notifications go to the Canvas and you can add a relative path with the href parameter. Just in case you don´t know this: it is not allowed to create a Canvas App just for the purpose of redirecting to an external websites. If you develop part of your App as a Canvas App, there should be no problem though.